# PDF with Password Encryption using oracle/PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, pdf-generation

Is there any way to create a password projected pdf file using PL/SQL without a third party jar

Comment: No. PL/SQL cannot natively create pdf files without the use of third party software/add-ons of some kind.

Comment: ok. Is there any free package available such as as_pdf3?

Comment: Have you tried as_pdf3? Looks like it has been around a while, but not updated recently as far as I can tell. I have no idea if it works with current versions of Oracle, or if it supports password protection (though I see no evidence that it does).

Comment: Yes, I'm working on this project using as_pdf3.  But I had tried with another package plpdf which works fine but it is trial version.  Package's Procedure name is plpdf.SetProtection(...). Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this also with another commercial package [OraPdfProtect](https://www.didisoft.com/ora-pdf-protect/tutorial/#password)

Example code below:

```
DECLARE 
  -- input PDF BLOB read handle
  pdf_file_handle BFILE;
  -- input PDF BLOB
  pdf_blob BLOB;  
  -- output encrypted PDF BLOB
  encrypted_pdf_blob BLOB;
 
  -- PDF permissions and password
  user_password VARCHAR2(200);
  owner_password VARCHAR2(200);
  pdf_permissions INTEGER;  
BEGIN
    DBMS_LOB.createtemporary(pdf_blob, TRUE);
    pdf_file_handle := BFILENAME('SSH_KEYS_DIR', '1.pdf'); -- directory name must be Upper case
 
    -- load the data into a BLOB
    DBMS_LOB.OPEN(pdf_file_handle, DBMS_LOB.LOB_READONLY);
    DBMS_LOB.LoadFromFile( pdf_blob, pdf_file_handle, DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(pdf_file_handle) );
    DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(pdf_file_handle);
 
    user_password := 'test123';
    owner_password := 'my password';
    pdf_permissions := ORA_PDF_PROTECT.NOCOPY + 
                              ORA_PDF_PROTECT.NOASSEMBLY +
                              ORA_PDF_PROTECT.NOMODIFYCONTENTS;
 
    encrypted_pdf_blob := ORA_PDF_PROTECT.ENCRYPT_PDF(pdf_blob, user_password, owner_password, pdf_permissions);
END;
/
```